# how to rotate a node in cocosjs?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-js

I am new to Cocos Creator.

trying to rotate a node with action.

```
openGates(){
    const gateLeft = this.node.getChildByName("gateLeft")
    const gateRight = this.node.getChildByName("gateLeft")

    const rotateLeft = cc.RotateBy.create(2, 40);
    const rotateRight = cc.RotateBy.create(2, -40);

    gateLeft.runAction(rotateLeft)
    gateRight.runAction(rotateRight)
},
```

and I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: cc.RotateBy.create is not a function
```

any idea?

Comment: Where is defined the `cc`? you could try to print the `cc` and check what functions are available

Comment: also you are setting `gateLeft` and `gateRight` to the same node, wonder how the concurrent actions are handled (after you resolve the ref to `cc` per Felipe's comment).

Answer (score 0):

please use `const rotateLeft = new cc.RotateBy(2, 40);`
instead of using create method.
also there is ";" missing in your first two statements